# What are all the options with css to overlap divs, without using position absolute?

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is my attempt at what I'm trying to solve, but all answers are we:

https://jsfiddle.net/L2qukchc/

it's just doing this:

```
  .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 }

.box-front {
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(57,70,78,1.2);
}

.box-back {
    display: flex;
    z-index: -1;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(57,70,78,1.2);
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

But I'm using negative margin (boo!).

I am using flexbox, but I want to have multiple layers [as would be attained through position:absolute and z-index].  The reason I am having trouble with absolute is that the layers are relative to each other, so writing a lot of breakpoints to solve this is not ideal.

The general question, "What are all the options with css to overlap divs", refers to whether or not I can position elements *relatively* but preventing my flexbox divs from making space for the newer elements I want to add [a la, layers].  Thanks!

Edit: A suggestion given to use relative layout works well:

https://jsfiddle.net/vdv09549/

wondering if there were others?

Comment: Right now your code isn't using flexbox and it's not clear at all why you've tagged this with css-animations as your question doesn't mention it. Can you add your current code or an [mcve] that uses flexbox and absolute positioning to your question?

Comment: updated with code that fits your suggestion, and removed the tag (brain fart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the mentioned negative margin is not suitable for this (see sample 3), I can only think of 2, `position: relative` in combo with `top`/`left` and `transform: translate`, where I would say the latter is probably the recommended one in most cases.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
.parent ~ .parent {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}

.parent.nr1 .child.nr2 {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  top: 20px;
}
.parent.nr2 .child.nr2 {
  transform: translate(-20px,20px);
}
.parent.nr3 .child.nr2 {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent nr1">
  <div class="child">Sample 1
  </div>
  <div class="child nr2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent nr2">
  <div class="child">Sample 2
  </div>
  <div class="child nr2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent nr3">
  <div class="child">Sample 3
  </div>
  <div class="child nr2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm currently doing, I was hoping there was some flexbox secret I hadn't known :(

Comment: @artiestie None of that info is available in the question, just to not use `position: absolute` ... and no, there is no hidden `flexbox` property that does something similar ... and no need either, since the given one's does a good job already

Comment: Is there something of similar to `display: none` (but is visible, of course) where it does not affect the layout?

Comment: @artiestie Yes, [`visibility: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood, i mean that it doesn't affect the layout, just like display: none (but is still visible) . I'll accept your answer anyways.

Comment: @artiestie Since `display: none` _does_ affect layout I don't understand what you mean by _but is still visible_

Comment: It **doesn't** affect the layout.  You might mean it _does_ matter, like if you change a visible element to display: none; then it can shift other elements, but that is an implicit side-effect.  You can read up on [display: none](http://learnlayout.com/display.html) if you don't understand what it means to affect the `layout`

Comment: @artiestie Could you show, maybe with a drawing, what you are looking for, and I hopefully will be able to give you an answer.

Comment: Not really, flexbox is the tool I am using for my layouts, but absolute positioning causes a lot of struggle with maintaining everything on animations and transitions.  So I wondered by the same way photoshop uses layering.  If there isn't an answer to it other than absolute positioning, or negative margins, then it's fine; that's why I accepted your answer.